# Finish activity from Another activity onBackPressed

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an Activity suppose `Activity_A` which calls `Activity_B` that Without showing anything goes to `Activity_C` using `startActivityforResult()`.

These work as expected, user Doesn't see `Activity_b` and if `Activity_c` returns the correct return_code `Activity_B` works according to the code
but if the user presses the back button it goes to an empty `Activity_B` (Since the information is returned from Activity_C) and then to `Activity_A` what I want is that if Back Button is pressed it goes to `Activity_A` otherwise work as it is working now. I used `Intent` to go to `Activity_A` using the Flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` but then it just moves `Activity_B` to the next position in Activity List.

There are multiple Activities before `Activity_A`, so using the Flag to clear top will not help.

I tried making an Activity variable which will call `finish()`, `onBackPressed()`
but it just returns with an error null pointer

Code on Activity_C

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),GalleryPreview.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    bg_edit1 abc = new bg_edit1();
    startActivityIfNeeded(intent,0);
    abc.t1.finish();
//  Intent i = new Intent("finish_activity");
//  sendBroadcast(i);
    finish();

}
```

Code On Activity_B

Using Broadcast Receiver( I think my implementation of broadcast receiver is wrong or it is not working )

```
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals("finish_activity")) {
                finish();
            }
        }
    };


registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("finish_activity"));
unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
```

error i got when trying Activity/AppCompatActivity method

```
void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.finish()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: You have to check activity is null before call finish()

Comment: I did that but then it just doesn't run, the activity is still present

Comment: Your question has been closed as a duplicate, but I don't think the duplicate question's answers will help you. Therefore I've reopened the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to finish another `Activity`. That's the wrong approach. To return directly to `A` from `C` when the back button is pressed, do this in `C`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,GalleryPreview.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

By adding `CLEAR_TOP` flag will automatically remove activity `B` from the stack. By adding `SINGLE_TOP` flag ensures that the existing instance of `A` will be used, and not a new instance of `A`.

You also do not need the `BroadcastReceiver` in activity `B`.